# FPGA Simulation Metastability

Tags: fpga, vivado, metastability

I have a quick question related to metastability during transfer of data across two clock signals. For a homework assignment, I designed a VHDL module to transfer data across two clock signals. To synchronize the two signals, the data was double-flopped before sending it to the destination. Clock A is set at 11MHz and Clock B is set at 100MHz. The module behaves mostly as expected but I wanted to make sure that I understand.

One of the questions on the homework is to raise the Clock A frequency until the design stops working, however whenever I try to do that the design still works. I believe this is due to the simulation in Vivado not being able to demonstrate metastability. If this design were actually implemented on hardware, wouldn't a double-flop be insufficient to sync clock B to clock A since the frequency of B is greater than A?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to look at this Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/570352/is-metastability-not-a-concern-in-cdc-if-the-signal-in-source-clock-is-at-least/570379#570379

Answer (score 1):

Vivado’s simulator is only a logic simulator. The synthesis and place-and-route tools will identify a clock domain cross as a warning, but the simulator will not model it accurately.

Instead you need to look at the MTBF calculations to predict how often metastability will occur. You probably will need to contact your Xilinx FAE for more details on the specific device you’re using.

This may be of interest: https://colinoflynn.com/2020/12/experimenting-with-metastability-and-multiple-clocks-on-fpgas/

Answer (score 0):

You can't eliminate metastability; you can only reduce its probability. Metastability will only occur if the data input to a flip-flop violates the setup or hold time requirement of that flip-flop, and your simulation may not have actually simulated those conditions. You may not have run the simulation long enough, or your clocks may not be asynchronous to each other.

Or, your simulated flip-flops might not properly model what happens when a setup or hold violation occurs. You haven't provided enough information to answer that.

In any event, two flip-flops is generally sufficient to reduce the risk of metastability to an acceptable level for consumer applications.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with others the simulator won’t show metastability.

However it should show functional limitations of your implementation with respect to frequency which is possibly what the question is getting at. IE if you use a 16-bit register to parallelize data from the faster domain to the slower domain you’ll lose data if clk_fast exceeds 16X of clk_slow.

Note it’s worth pointing out the specific problem with metastability - if a metastable output goes to 2 places and gets interpreted as different values.